# Time to doubling value in Google Spreadsheet column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

There is a Google Spreadsheet, where each row is a day-by-day. And there is a column with monotonously increasing values. I need to make a parallel column with number of days to doubling values in original column. The following is an example

```
 Data   Original  New     !  Illustration
04/01          1          !
04/02          2    1     !  2 / 2 = 1     => 04/01
04/03          4    1     !  4 / 2 = 2     => 04/02
04/04          5    2     !  5 / 2 = 2.5   => 04/02
04/05          8    2     !  8 / 2 = 4     => 04/03
04/06         10    2     ! 10 / 2 = 5     => 04/04
04/07         12    3     ! 12 / 2 = 6     => 04/04
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `C` - is original column. Then the formula is following:

```
=ROW() - MATCH(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("C"& ROW())/2,C:C,1), C:C)
```

**Explanation**

- `"C"& ROW()` is a cell of original column on current row
- `INDIRECT` allows to get cell value by string representation of the cell address
- `VLOOKUP` searches for 0.5 of the value for current cell in original column
- `MATCH` defines row with 0.5 of the value for current cell in original column